# Does a Master Assassin sent out on a Mediterranean defense mission leave their den vulnerable to Templar attack?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

As the question says, if I send a Master Assassin off on a Mediterranean defense mission, does it leave their assigned den vulnerable to a Templar attack?

When I get my 7 dens all assigned Master Assassins, can I risk using them for Mediterranean defense missions and still be safe from Templar attacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Not for regular missions or even if you station them in a city.  They will remain den masters there and your dens will be protected.  Though keep in mind, if they are killed in their missions, the den will (probably) be unprotected and will have to assign another one to the respective den and train to master.  I don't know what happens in this case but you probably won't have to do the associated missions again.

Comment: I'm tempted to kill one off to see, but at this point since I control every city I don't think there are actually any missions hard enough that they don't have 100% base odds!

Comment: Master Assassins can handle 5 diamond missions alone.  They need the help on 6 diamond missions as they have about ~76% success there.  Though that's not counting the starred missions.  I think they can handle a 4 star mission alone.  That would be a good way to kill them off if someone did want to try.

Comment: Yeah, but are there any regenerating 6 diamond missions?  Maybe just need to do enough other ones and will get one randomly, hmmm...

Comment: Yeah, they appear regularly for me on some cities (and I too have 100% control over all the cities).  Look at the ones toward the bottom of the list.  (I don't have the game running at the moment so I don't recall which ones they were)

Comment: If you send one off on ah 76% success mission theyll still come back they dont seem to die, ive tried killing 2, your stuck with the ones you get. what i want to know is how to get rid of them, ive heared you could send them off on the medaterranean mission and they stay out there. I cant seem to do that, im doing everything to try to get some new assassins or atleast get my other one to master assassins. any tips?

Comment: @Shinrai - if you're looking to kill off an assassin there's a quick way to do it: send everyone else away, stand next to a scaffold and summon them. If they jump on the scaffold or climb back up it go high profile and pull it down. That's an insta-kill for any level of assassin.

Comment: @Truhbuhll: If you're trying to kill off one of your den masters, make sure you're not trying to send your first master assassin on missions.  [I don't think that one could die ever](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46085/8995).  Try sending one of the others on a **six star** mission _alone_ and see how that goes.  That's probably the best chance you have at killing one of them (and is not something I'm willing to test).