# First denmaster features in end-game?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

Spoilers.

Towards the end of AC: Revelations,

> Yusuf gets killed.

During a cutscene shortly afterwards, Ezio picks out an assassin and says something along the lines of "You, Assassin,

> Yusuf spoke highly of you, can you take over?"

Is this the first denmaster - the one that is already chosen for you, and is on a mission for much of the start of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe so.  The first master assassin you train is the one who he is referring to.  He doesn't call him by name as that's random still.  It's highly unlikely that he could be referring to any other (random) assassin.

> That assassin started off at level 10 immediately so must have worked with Yusuf for a long time.  IIRC, he could not even be killed, he will be left "unconscious" and recover eventually instead of dying.  (Somehow, one of my assassin's were "knocked out" when I called on them in battle, I believe it was my den master at the time)

Comment: I think he just meant for the Constantinople group, not all Assassin's in general.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, but I couldn't really remember what he looked like. If someone got a randomly-generated female character as their first den master and the character in the cutscene was female, that might seal it.

Comment: @Rawling: In my game and every other walkthrough video I could find on YouTube shows the same guy, balding with a little moustache.  I don't know if I could reliably describe him, just look at a video.

Comment: @Rawling: Here's such a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=SL&feature=player_detailpage&v=6hRqDFTyJ0E#t=526s.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the exact same guy as mine. I wonder if it's possible to train another assassin up to 10 and choose them as the den leader instead...